# How best to Calculate Nth subscription renewal?

Tags: database, postgresql, etl, data-warehouse

So I have a transaction table (postgres) that inserts a new row whenever a user renews their subscription for our service. The table `subscription` looks like this:

```
+--------+--------+------------+
| userId | prodId | renew_date |
+--------+--------+------------+
|      1 |      1 | 2018-05-01 |
|      1 |      1 | 2018-06-01 |
|      1 |      1 | 2018-07-01 |
|      2 |      3 | 2017-04-16 |
|      2 |      3 | 2017-05-16 |
+--------+--------+------------+
```

If the analysts want to figure out the Nth renewal or latest renewal for a particular user or product, I have two solutions to give them that:

1.) During my ETL process, I truncate the DW warehouse target table and re-populate it with:

```
select *
  , row_number() over (partition by userId, productId order by renew_date asc) as nth_renewal
from subscription
```

I can't think of a way where i can +1 to the previous renewal if I were to do incremental updates, what if this is the customers first renewal?

2.) I just copy the exact OLTP table over to the data warehouse and do incremental updates every day. This way, I let the analysts calculate the nth renewal themselves. (also as a follow up question: is it ever OK to have a duplicate copy of a transactional table in my data warehouse?)

Comment: I am not quiet sure what you are trying to do. Please add an expected output. It seems that you do not search for any window functions (row_number is the right choice). You are trying to update something. What is it?  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1b7e4bede113fc038d9965f890bafb5b

Comment: @S-Man, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b70a49287e46b24249065cb764f96977 the last sample shows the expected output. The goal is to show the Nth renewal each customer has for each product.

Comment: This is the query you showed, am I right? I am still not sure what is your problem. Do you want to add a WHERE clause (WHERE 3 = row_number) to get the 3rd renewal?